# ASP.NET: Thread-safety in a file-based database

Tags: asp.net

I have worked a bit with ASP.NET before. I was using a MS SQL server to store and retrieve data to display in some dynamic pages in one project I started to learn ASP.NET a bit. Now I am about to start a new project but this time I would like to store the data in a file-based database , like say, an Access file. This project is also a hobby project and I'm not afraid of the scaling problem because perhaps only 3 users will be using the application at the same time and no be data traffic will be expected.

Now , about my question: using a MS SQL database there is no problem with several users reading-writing to the Db at the same time because the DB engine will take care of this, but using a file-based database with ADO.NET will be a problem in that case, am I right?

What I mean, do I need to take care of multiuser synchronization myself (using some synchronization mechanism, lock, mutex, whatever) to guarantee thread safety when working with the database or does ADO.NET takes care of that as well?

Should I use perhaps a singleton class for the data layer?

Comment: Why would you resort to Access? With MS SQL, you can also used a file (an .mdf file) as a data store.

Comment: The question is not why. The question is about thread-safety for file based databases.

Comment: And I'm saying that MS SQL is also file based.

Comment: Yes but MS SQL already handles multi threading per se. And yes I know Access should not be used in that case, I understand perfectly the nature of web applications. But that's NOT the question, people. It's like asking "where can I buy a bicycle in NY" and getting the response "You should buy a car in NY"...Sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fretje mentioned, ms access isn't a good db to use for web applications. But assuming you already know that there isn't anything special you need to do in order to use a access db with ado.net (other then using the right provider of course). ADO.Net will handle all that for you.

About having you data layer as singleton, I would really not recommend that.

Comment: OK, that's an answer, thank you. Is there any particular reason why Singleton classes are not a good idea in this particular case?

Comment: @Lobuno, Singleton classes should only be used for classes that are expensive to create and therefore you want to maintain the same instance as long as your application is alive. If you use it for anything else you will loose a lot of flexibility and it will be harder to maintain.